# Ubuntu 14.04 Nvidea GT 840M Graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am having trouble with my Geforce GT 840M on my brand new Ubuntu instillation, it does not seem to be listed as my graphics card.

[Details Page](https://imgur.com/a3TF7cC.png)

However the card is listed under lspci

[lspci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMMPK.png)

I have tried installing drivers for it from the Nvidia website but after going through the instillation process ( cntrl+alt+1 then,  sudo service lightdm stop , then sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.32.run ) My instillation no longer works. When logging into a user the top bar as well as the dock do not appear.

I also seem to be unable to get drivers for it from the software & updates menu as it tells me that there are no updates available.

Comment: My answer to another question might be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/518985/ubuntu-14-04-and-nvidia-geforce-840m-compatability-on-64-bit-laptop