# Problem installing Nvidia drivers on 840m (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

Just got an MSI GP70 2PE Laptop. The laptop has an Nvidia 840m and I need to utilize the GPU for my work. I've tried following the instructions (posted here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/nvidia-driver-337-25), but when I get to the login screen there is a crash report prompt and I am unable to do anything else (I can CTRL+ALT+F1 and get a working terminal, but that's it). I've also tried skipping over the install of nvidia331-updates-dev and just using the .run file downloaded from Nvidia, but that causes the same issue. Any ideas on what could be happening?

Note that a fresh install of Ubuntu works fine. However, when I do boot into that, just before the login screen appears I see a two line message starting something about 'nouveau unknown chipset'.

Also, under the Addition Drivers dialog it simply states "No proprietary drivers in use".

Here is a copy of my Xorg.0.log: http://textuploader.com/okaq

Comment: Welcome to AU! I find those instructions a bit shoddy. Did you try to install the Nvidia driver through `jockey` (dubbed “Additional drivers”)? Can you [include](https://askubuntu.com/posts/530724/edit) the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` in your question please?

Comment: Sorry for the mess of a message above. Just to clarify, when I open Additional Drivers there are no drivers listed to choose from, simply a line saying "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system".

Comment: So besides the Nvidia GPU you have integrated graphics from Intel. Unfortunately I don't know how to deal with dual graphics adapters. What I can however see, is that there's no kernel module for the Nvidia driver. Can you provide the output of `LC_MESSAGES=C dpkg --list nvidia-\*` please? It should tell us more about what driver packages are installed.

Comment: My answer to this question might be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/518985/ubuntu-14-04-and-nvidia-geforce-840m-compatability-on-64-bit-laptop

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get mine working using xorg-edgers.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo reboot
```

Reboot and go to your additional drivers and usually I find the 340 driver installed and the nouveau driver.  Select the nvidia driver let it switch drivers and reboot again.  when the driver is installed nvidia-xserver settings show all the info about your card.  I have a MSI gp60 same gpu.  However I have never been able to get it to top randomly freezing.  And when i open up system details it still says my intel chip is the gpu.
I also get the unknown chipset error.