# Problem with nvidia 820m

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-prime

I have laptop asus X455ld with core i3 and I installed Ubuntu 14.04. However, I can't switch to nvidia 820m graphic card. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Take a look at this question: [How to install nvidia GT 840m driver in Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/551401/how-to-install-nvidia-gt-840m-driver-in-ubuntu-14-04) about a similar graphics card to yours (i3 processor and an NVIDIA GT 840M graphics card), except that he installed the wrong graphics card driver to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I have same laptop as yours. 
I installed Nvidia drivers successfully. If possible check whether your system is 32-bit or 64-bit and after installation don't start the `lightdm` service.

Open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo service lightdm stop 
sudo init 3
sudo chmod +x <file_name>.run
sudo sh <file_name>.run
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo service lightdm start
sudo reboot
```

If it's not working, then try reinstalling your desktop environment.