# Ubuntu characters missing with Nvidia GeForce 840M and Nouveau driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

I recently bought a new laptop (ASUS-X555LN) with a 840M graphics card in it. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit with its install DVD, during and after the install, there are missing characters, like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Before this, I executed the commands from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/557395/179008), but did **not** choose to activate the Nvidia drivers from the "Additional Drivers" menu, I'm still using the Nouveau driver.

Anyway, I'm confused. I already browsed a lot of discussions (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518985/ubuntu-14-04-and-nvidia-geforce-840m-compatability-on-64-bit-laptop) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551401/how-to-install-nvidia-gt-840m-driver-in-ubuntu-14-04)) and tried the proposed solutions to the graphics card problem, but all of the times I ended up messing the desktop, (sometimes blank, sometimes 640x480). What is a guaranteed way of having no problems with my graphics card? Is there such a way?

Currently my driver options are: (also another example of my problem :) )

[image]

Which driver should I use?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

While there is no way of not having graphics card problems, you can choose the newest, stable driver that can help.  NVIDIA is listing version 349.16 as the newest driver, so that is the one that I would choose.

After choosing that driver, use the nvidia-settings as a elevated user to configure higher settings.  From a terminal window type in `sudo nvidia-settings`.  Apply your new settings and save them to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` so the settings are permanent.

Comment: +1 you deserve but you should improve your answer to get more attention

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  There were more comments earlier that were removed.  This turned out to be only a suggestion answer.  The point system that was set up on this site was preventing me from commenting on posts.  I have seen others trying to comment or +1 my posts but could not due to points restrictions.