# Ubuntu 15.04 is warming Lenovo Z50-70 too much

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lenovo, 15.04, jupiter

Yesterday I installed **Ubuntu 15.04** on my **Lenovo Z50-70** with **NVidia GForce 840M**, but my laptop is too hot since I installed it. I installed **Jupiter** (through) Jolicloud raring repositories), TLP, and drivers using this guide [Ubuntu 14.04 and Nvidia GeForce (840M) compatability on 64-bit laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518985/ubuntu-14-04-and-nvidia-geforce-840m-compatability-on-64-bit-laptop) but I can't find the solution. Please help me!

It's not a **CPU-working** problem because `top` command returns that the worst process takes 2.0% of CPU. But the cooler fans are always at maximum and pc is too hot. What can I do? On my laptop there is also an **Intel Integrated Graphic Card**.

Thanks Pilot 6. This is the output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380d]
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
03:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] [10de:1341] (rev a2)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380d]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

I don't know if it's CPU or GPU. I'm not expert. I think is GPU because the cpu-working is not high.

Comment: Please add output of "lspci -knn | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2" terminal command to your question.

Comment: Is it the **CPU** or **GPU** which is getting hot? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Is nvidia-prime installed?

Comment: Yes it is installed.

Comment: did you install lm-sensors and run sudo sensors-detect?

Comment: I just installed it. What I can do with that?