# ubuntu 15.04 wakeup from sleep : unclaimed register

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, 15.04, suspend

I have Ubuntu 15.04 installed on Lenovo Z5070 laptop. For Nvidia 840m I have `nvidia-346` installed. While waking up from sleep I get the following error on a black screen

```
drm: hsw_uncalimed_reg_clear Error unknown claimed register before writing to c7204
drm: hsw_unclaimed_reg_check
```

I `ssh`ed into my system in that state. Here's the tail of `xorg.0.log`

```
[    70.924] (II) modeset(G0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5579
[    70.924] (II) modeset(G0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    70.924] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  136.62  1920 1964 1992 2070  1080 1082 1086 1100 -hsync -vsync (66.0 kHz eP)
[    70.924] reporting 3 4 37 280
[    71.376] reporting 3 4 37 280
[    73.380] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7C75F152E85183199599C3E0B919739C0EE668AA.xkm
[    76.529] reporting 3 4 37 280
[    77.733] reporting 3 4 37 280
[    77.834] (II) modeset(G0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5579
[    77.834] (II) modeset(G0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    77.834] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  136.62  1920 1964 1992 2070  1080 1082 1086 1100 -hsync -vsync (66.0 kHz eP)
[    77.834] reporting 3 4 37 280
[    77.857] reporting 3 4 37 280
[   110.090] reporting 3 4 37 280
[   121.436] reporting 3 4 37 280
[   167.116] reporting 3 4 37 280
[   178.272] reporting 3 4 37 280
[   217.841] reporting 3 4 37 280
[   243.717] reporting 3 4 37 280
[  1345.073] reporting 3 4 37 280
[  1533.403] reporting 3 4 37 280
[  1537.357] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Failed to enter interactive mode. 
[  1537.357] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[  1537.358] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to allocate primary buffer: error
[  1537.358] (EE) NVIDIA(0):  *** Aborting ***
```

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by installing bumblebee with nvidia-346. The detailed solution is available at https://askubuntu.com/a/534567