# GPU has fallen off the bus (Nvidia) RTX 2060S

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

At a random moment, such an error appears and the system freezes dead. After a reboot, most likely, there may not be such an error, but if I turn off the computer for a long time and turn it back on, the error will come immediately and everything will start again. Most often, it arrives if there is some kind of load (for example, any games or when I work a lot, a lot of things openly). If, for example, I only have my browser open and I watch the videos, the system does not die. But as soon as there is some kind of load, then in about 10 minutes this error flies out. Previously this did not happen for about a year or half a year. I tried a bunch of different distros, retried about half of the kernel settings ([GPU has fallen off the bus (Nvidia)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868321/gpu-has-fallen-off-the-bus-nvidia)).

[image]

Comment: This happens on different distributions, ranging from vanilla os to endeavour. LTS has not tried(Except maybe linux mint), tried Ubuntu Desktop. I've tried non-systemd distributions.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 version.